# Interpetation of /proc/sys/kernel/shmall

Tags: debian, virtual-memory, amazon-ec2, shared-memory

Unless I am wrong. the value of `/proc/sys/kernel/shmall` indicates the  the total amount of shared memory, in bytes, that can be allocated to the system.

I am on a `t2.micro` ec2 debian instance, and I get this:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/shmall
18446744073692774399
```

I do not suppose this means that the total allocatable amount of shared memory is around **0.02 zettabytes** ...

Answer (score 0):

Right, it should be enough for anybody, defined as `(ULONG_MAX - (1UL << 24))`. Note, though, that it isn't a per-process, but an overall value. See http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/include/uapi/linux/shm.h#L13:

```
 * SHMMNI, SHMMAX and SHMALL are default upper limits which can be
 * modified by sysctl. The SHMMAX and SHMALL values have been chosen to
 * be as large possible without facilitating scenarios where userspace
 * causes overflows when adjusting the limits via operations of the form
 * "retrieve current limit; add X; update limit". It is therefore not
 * advised to make SHMMAX and SHMALL any larger. These limits are
 * suitable for both 32 and 64-bit systems.
```